# How do you access an existing value inside mongoose query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

Pretty much I have built an application for users to receive points and every 10 points they should receive a trophy. RewardPoints are integer and Trophies is an array. I want to increment the rewardPoints when user pays and at the same time do the validation to push a trophy if existing points after the update are 10 or 20 or 30 etc. I've somehow made it using normal js without the push(simply using math.floor() to set the numoftrophies) inside the .exec() function but i have other problems occurring on user.save(). I want to transform this:

```
  User.findById(req.body.userID).exec(function(err, user){
    if (err){throw err;}        

    user.rewardPoints = user.rewardPoints + 1;

    let trophyNumbers =  Math.floor(user.rewardPoints / 10)

    user.trophies = trophyNumbers;

    user.save();

})
```

to something like this:

```
    User.update({ _id: req.body.userID },
    {
        $inc: { rewardPoints: 1 },
        $push: {
            trophies: {
                trophy: new Date(),
                trophyNum: Math.floor(rewardPoints / 10)
            }
        }
    })
    .exec(function (err, res) {

        if (err) { throw err; }
        //trophy must be added every 10 points
        console.log('points saved');
    });
```

How do i access the existing rewardPoints inside $push of trophies? If anyone could help I'd be really appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 User.findById(req.body.userID).exec(function (err, user) {
        if (err) { throw err; }

        let newRewardPts = user.rewardPoints + 1;

        User.update({ _id: req.body.userID },
          {
            $inc: { rewardPoints: 1 },
            $addToSet: {
              trophy: new Date(),
              trophyNum: Math.floor(newRewardPts / 10)
            }
          })
          .exec(function (err, res) {

            if (err) { throw err; }
            //trophy must be added every 10 points
            console.log('points saved');
          });

      })
```